# Determining if currently renaming a file in Windows Explorer

Tags: windows, shell, rename, explorer

I am trying to check a Windows Explorer view to see if a file name is currently being renamed / edited when typing.

I have a system hook installed that monitors the keyboard for specific keystrokes and fires certain events. This is done in this manner:

- If the keyboard hook sees the key pressed it fires a message to another thread and continue processing other system hooks.
- Other thread receives the message and checks to see if an Explorer window is active and gets the interface to the IFolderView2.
- Call IFolderView2::GetFocusedItem() to get the focused item in the folder view.
- Check if the focused item is being renamed / is in edit mode (SVSI_EDIT) using IFolderView2:: GetSelectionState() - **this is the part that fails**
- If not in rename mode perform an action on that file.

I've tried everything on Windows 7 but the SVSI_EDIT flag (0x00000002 specifically) is never returned. It's always (SVSI_FOCUSED | SVSI_SELECT) regardless of if the file is being renamed. Setting the SVSI_EDIT flag with works with IFolderView::SelectItem with the flag puts it into rename mode but I want to determine if it's in this mode already.

This has only been tested on Windows 7 x64 so far.

Does anyone know a way to determine if Explorer / the IFolderView etc. is currently in the rename file state? Any sneaky method will do if it's not possible through these interfaces.

Comment: +1 You did your research very, very well. Kudos to you.

Comment: I would have preferred not to have to. I guess nobody has a clue on this one..?

Comment: I don't, sorry. If you are in a bind, though, you can try spreading out to other forums for help.

Comment: absolutely, any hints on which forums? I'm more of a reader of them than a poster as you can see this is my first on SO for the reason this seems unbreakable... it may be useful to follow through for posterity (appreciated all input!)

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. I really don't use forums for this sort of stuff, so I would just try to find a busy one. However, following through for posterity isn't a bad idea because then others in the future can benefit from your solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If one file in in renaming mode, Windows will create a EDIT control at the position of the item. So things got straight:

1. Find the currently-focused control.
2. Get the CLASS of the control.
3. Check whether it's CLASS is an EDIT.

On [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34752/Control-in-Focus-in-Other-Processes) there is a great example about how to find the focused control. To get the CLASS name of that control, use [GetClassName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633582(v=vs.85).aspx) API.

Comment: You, sir, are a champion. Works perfectly, although GetClassName() is returning "Edit" on Win10, who knows what it is on other OS's so a case insensitive compare is warranted. I had no idea you could capture focus window from another process in this fashion.